# What is a metatype in nestjs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Reading the official nestjs doc, I've come across the following implementation of `ValidationPipe`:

```
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

@Injectable()
export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
  async transform(value: any, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metatype)) {
      return value;
    }
    const object = plainToClass(metatype, value);
    const errors = await validate(object);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
    }
    return value;
  }

  private toValidate(metatype: Function): boolean {
    const types: Function[] = [String, Boolean, Number, Array, Object];
    return !types.includes(metatype);
  }
}
```

I don't understand the logic put in the `transform` method. It would be great if someone would explain this piece line by line. I think the problem steams from the fact that I don't quite understand what `ArgumentMetadata` is and where it comes from.

Answer (score 5):

`Metatype` is the class type of the object being passed into the pipe, retrieved via reflection and some magic [but if](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/core/helpers/external-context-creator.ts#L284) [you wanna](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/core/pipes/pipes-consumer.ts) [look here's](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/core/pipes/params-token-factory.ts) [the code](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/core/pipes/pipes-context-creator.ts).

Essentially, if you have `@Body() body: MyCustomClass` then metatype will be equal to `MyCustomClass`. This is necessary for the `plainToClass` method so it knows what class it is serializing the JSON into. If you are working with JavaScript or don't provide a type, then metatype will be undefined